# Swift Firebase Project Letting Users Sign Up But Not Sign In, Shows Error Instead

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am making a login/sign up screen for one of my recent Xcode projects. My project uses Firebase, Swift, and Xcode 11.0.

Everything, including the setup, produced no errors and was pretty smooth until I started to make the sign-in page. After I ran the project(and the device I ran it on showed the sign-in page) and entered my email address, account password...ect., and pressed sign up, everything worked.

But then the next time I ran it, entered the same email address and password as I had on the first time, and pressed the sign-in/sign up button, it wouldn't take me to the desired page I had linked it to, as it was supposed to do, and had done on the first time I had entered the same email, and showed this error:

**nw_connection_receive_internal_block_invoke [C1] Receive reply failed with error "Operation canceled"**

The code does work, though, if you enter a new email. But only for the first time.

Here's my view controller:

```swift
@IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text{
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
                if error != nil {
                    // Create Account
                }else{
                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user?.user.uid)!, forKey: ("Key_UID"))
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not sign in code, that's create user code. Once you've created a user, you cannot create the same user because it already exists. When you try to create the user again, error != nil but you're not handling the error with anything so it just silently fails.

Comment: thanks, that worked for me